# 2 raised to what power, is greater than 1,000,000,000? print the answer(answer must be int)

Tags: python

I am trying to find this answer using `while` loop but I have not been able to write the code.

I was trying the below code:

```py
base=2
num=1

while base**num > 1000000000:
   print(num)
   num +=1
```

Comment: You want `while base**num<1000000000`. Currently base^num (i.e. 2^1) is less than 1M, so the while loop is not executed and nothing is printed

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using log.

```
    import math
    res = math.log(1000000000,2)
    num = int(res)+1 # taking ceiling and not floor of the log as 2^floor will result in a number less than 1000000000
    print(num)
```

Using a while loop will be inefficient and computationally very expensive, especially for large numbers

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is reversed. It should be `base**num>1000000000`. That's an extremely inefficient way of calculating powers though.

Use :

```
>>> math.ceil(math.log2(1000000000))
30
```

[math.log2](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/math.html#math.log2) is a specialized version of `log`. You could even use `int.bit_length` because in binary, numbers are represented using as many digits as their base-2. Unless the number is an exact power of 2, 2^digits is guarantee to return a larger number

```
>>> int.bit_length(1000000000)
30
```

The power you need to raise a "base" (in this case 2) to get a number is the base-N logarithm of that number. In this case you're looking for the base-2 logarithm of 1000000000.

The result of is `math.log2(1000000000)` is `29.897` though, so you need its ceiling to get the next higher integer number

```
>>> math.log2(1000000000)
29.897352853986263
```

Logarithms are so useful CPUs have built-in commands to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood properly your question, but if so...

You are trying to find a number that, used to elevate 2, gives you a number greater than 1'000'000'000.
The condition is wrong, because it should be:

```py
while (base**num < 1000000000):
   num += 1

print(num)
```

So, it increments `num` while it isn't greater than your "limit" `1'000'000'000`.

I suggest you to use the logarithm function, to avoid the loop:

```py
import math

num = (int) math.log(1000000000, 2)
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
base = 2
power = 1
value = 1000000000
output = base**power
while output <= value:
    power+=1
    output = base**power
    print(output, power)`enter code here`
    
print(power)
```

Comment: Could you please kindly add some comments/short description on why/how your solution works?

Answer (score -1):

after define the variable and value is getting output as expected, check the below code.

```
base = 2
num = 0
while (base**num < 1000000000):
    num += 1
print(num)
```

Output will come:- 30